# How to do an inner join on Facebook FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Ok, so I'm querying two FQL tables: Events and event_members. On one query I get all events from the user and his friends (let's call this $events), and on the other query I get all the members 'attending' to all those events (let's call it $attendingmembers).
Both queries are returned as arrays on php, and as you may already know FQL doesn't allow INNER JOINS.

What I want to do is to "normalize" the data, so that I join both results and I get a single array with all the event details AND the amount of people attending to that event. Both arrays share a common KEY: eid.

On sql it would be very easy... Inner JOIN. BUT on FQL there is no Inner join, so I think I should do the join 'php-side', with array_intersect o something similar, but i can't get to find the way to do it.

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An inner join would not give you the number of people attending. A count would. Also, that is not "normalizing" the data, it's confusing to think of it as such.

To do this in a programming language (such as PHP), just iterate through the array and increment a counter each time the element is found.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to count the number of members in event_members to get the amount attending. And I think It's better to use the count function rather than iterating through the array.

But after that I need to join the data so that I get only 1 array, combining the details of the event and the count information from the 2nd array.